# What is argmin function described in below equation?

Tags: matlab, math, mathematical-optimization

[image]

What the function argmin do here? Please explain or give any hint regarding it. I am needed to implement this function on MATLAB. Is there any direct command avaiable there?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is related purely to Mathematics.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

argmin is the argument (k) that minimizes the function value (sigma_ij), so the argmin will be 1, 2, 3, or 4

Comment: is there any command in matlab for computing this function?